# Deduplicate a list of lm objects in R

Tags: r, list, duplicates

I have a `list` of `lm` models objects with possible repeated, so I'd like to find a way of checking if some of these `lm` objects are equal, if so them delete it. In words, I want to "deduplicate" my `list`.

I'd appreciate very much any help.

An example of the problem:

```
## Creates outcome and predictors
outcome    <- c(names(mtcars)[1:3])
predictors <- c(names(mtcars)[4:11])
dataset    <- mtcars

## Creates model list
model_list <- lapply(seq_along((predictors)), function(n) {
  left_hand_side  <- outcome[1]
  right_hand_side <- apply(X = combn(predictors, n), MARGIN = 2, paste, collapse = " + ")
  paste(left_hand_side, right_hand_side, sep = "  ~  ")
})

## Convert model list into a verctor
model_vector <- unlist(model_list)

## Fit linear models to all itens from the vector of models
list_of_fit <- lapply(model_vector, function(x) {
  formula    <- as.formula(x)
  fit        <- step(lm(formula, data = dataset))
  fit
})

# Exclude possible missing
list_of_fit <- Filter(Negate(function(x) is.null(unlist(x))), list_of_fit)

# These models are the same in my list
lm253 <- list_of_fit[[253]];lm253
lm254 <- list_of_fit[[254]];lm254
lm255 <- list_of_fit[[255]];lm255
```

I want to exclude duplicated entries in `list_of_fit`.

Comment: In a `vector` or `data.frame`, you could use `duplicated()`, but there does not seem to be an analogue for `list`s. You could in principle nest two `for` loops and manually test two entries against each other using `identical` (be sure to read `?identical`!).

Comment: Note that `all.equal(lm253, lm254)` does not return `TRUE`, so they aren't really duplicates. But you seem to just care about the call being duplicated?

Comment: Sorry for my poor English, I'm from BR and I'm learning your language! thanks for your correction Stephan Kolassa.

Comment: shadow, I think it looks better to compare the models by their formulas as suggestion made by Roland shown below. The problem for me is on how to code that in R. I'm new R user.

Comment: Does my suggestion not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

It seems wasteful to fit so many models and then throw away most of them. Your object names make your code hard to read for me, but it seems your models can be distinguished based on their formula. Maybe this helps:

```
lista_de_ajustes[!duplicated(vapply(lista_de_ajustes, 
                                    function(m) deparse(m$call), 
                                    FUN.VALUE = "a"))]
```

Comment: Error in duplicated (vapply (lista_de_ajustes, function (m) Deparse ($ m call):
   error in the evaluation of the argument 'x' in the selection of the method for function 'duplicated': 'Error in vapply (lista_de_ajustes, function (m) Deparse ($ m call), FUN.VALUE = "a"): values must be of length 1,but the result of FUN (X [[57]]) has length 2

Comment: Roland, I corrected the text code. The suggestion did not work for my set of models. An error was returned.

Comment: Sorry, but the call in the error message doesn't look identical to my code.

Comment: My mistake, "Error in duplicated(vapply(lista_de_ajustes, function(m) deparse(m$call): error in the evaluation of the argument 'x' in the method of selection for the function 'duplicated': 'Error in vapply(lista_de_ajustes, function(m) deparse(m$call), FUN.VALUE = "a") : 
  values must be of length 1, but the result of FUN (X [[57]]) has length 2 "

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple correction in you code Roland, so it worked for me.
I changed from `deparse(m$call)` to `deparse(formula(m))`, due this I'm able to compare the complete formulas.

```
lista_de_ajustes[!duplicated(vapply(lista_de_ajustes, function(m) deparse(formula(m)), FUN.VALUE = "a"))]
```

Thank you very much!